# Social Media buttons appearing on pages

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm working on adding social media buttons on all posts. I am using this code:

```
function wintersong_custom_buttons($content) {
    $new_content = 'Button HTML here.';
    $content .= $new_content;   

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wintersong_custom_buttons');
```

I have tried to add `is_single` but then the buttons only appear when you view a post.

I want them to appear only...

- when the user is viewing all posts
- when the user has clicked on a post and is viewing all content of it

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
function wintersong_custom_buttons($content) {
    if( ! is_page() ) {
        $new_content = 'Button HTML here';
        $content .= $new_content;   
        $content = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($content));
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wintersong_custom_buttons');
```